# Macro cannot acces files on the network

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am attempting to edit some Word files in a network path, put the Macro doesn't start. If i change the path to a local path (C: or D:), it works fine. I have full access to the network path.

```
Directory = "S:\PROJETS\GT R\test\"
FType = "*.doc"

ChDir Directory
FName = Dir(FType)

Documents.Open FileName:=Directory & FName
```

What seems to be the problem ?

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/225692/52365

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the `Dir` function, there is no need to change directory first. Try this

```
Directory = "S:\PROJETS\GT R\test\"
FType = "*.doc"

FName = Dir(Directory & FType)

Documents.Open FileName:=Directory & FName
```